# Creating Hierarchical Data using closure in C#?

Tags: c#, closures

I'm trying to create Hierarchical Data using closure in c#. I have a method "**Pair**" which looks like this:

```
  public static Func<string, int> Pair(int x,Func<string, int> y)
    {

        Func<string, int> pair =
               (a) =>
               {
                   if (a == "con") return x;
                   if (a == "crd") return y("con");
                   throw new Exception();
               };

        return pair;
    }
```

Than I create my  Hierarchical Data as shown below :

```
      var pair = Pair(1,
                        Pair(2,
                              Pair(3,
                                    Pair(4,null))));
```

which when represented visually, look like this :
[image]

I am aware that this approach is flawed because I can not get/print all the values stored in pair. I can not do some thing like this :

```
 public static void Print(Func<string, int> pair)
    {
        if (pair("crd") == null) return;
        Console.WriteLine(pair("con"));
        Print(pair("crd")); //Compilation Error
    }
```

Can somebody tell me how to achieve this in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your Pair closure needs to be able to return two different types of objects: an int if you ask for the "con", and the next closure in line if you ask for the "crd".

Here's one possible implementation:

Use a dynamic so that you can return either.

```
public static Func<string, dynamic> Pair(int x, Func<string, dynamic> y)
{
    Func<string, dynamic> pair =
           (a) =>
           {
               if (a == "con") return x;
               if (a == "crd") return y;
               throw new Exception();
           };

    return pair;
}

public static void Print(Func<string, dynamic> pair)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var next = pair("crd");
        Console.WriteLine((next == null ? "-":"+") +"> " + pair("con"));
        if (next != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("|");
            pair = (x) => next(x);
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

test:

```
var pair = Pair(1,
            Pair(2,
                  Pair(3,
                        Pair(4, null))));

Print(pair);
```

output:

```
+> 1
|
+> 2
|
+> 3
|
-> 4
```